# Firebase database borrar item array

Tags: array, firebase

No consigo borrar los item que tengo en un array con el codigo siguiente, probando de dos maneras pero nada os paso la imagen de la bbdd y el codigo.

Puede que sea haciendolo con onDataChange???

```
public void deleteEvent(View view) {


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child( uiD ).child( "events" ).child( code );
    databaseReference.removeValue();
    users.getevents().remove( 1 );


}
```

Codigo para el ingreso en el array

```
public boolean checkAdd(String codigo ){

    for ( String item : users.getevents()){
        if(codigo.equals(item)){
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;

}

 if(checkAdd(codigo)){
     users.getevents().add(codigo);
 }
```

y luego se obtiene desde firebase

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Events" ).child( code );

```
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Event event = dataSnapshot.getValue( Event.class );
            mTitle.setText( event.getTitle() );
            mDescription.setText( event.getDescription() );
            dataEvent=event.getDateEvent();
            code=event.getCode();
            url=event.getFoto();
            mCode.setText(event.getCode());
            ano=event.getAno();
            mes=event.getMes();
            dia=event.getDia();
            countDate();//diferencia fechas
            url();//foto evento
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(final DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    } );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias detallar donde obtienes code en tu ultimo child ?

Comment: Code se rescata de la base de datos, es el codigo de un evento que luego se almacena en el array de la imagen

Comment: claro, pero se lo estas pasando por algun lado, un edittext o algun string que creas dentro del codigo no ? por que a ese valor le seteas 0,1,2,3,4,5 en ese child(code)

Comment: Si, pero no entiendo exactamente lo que me pides, quieres saber el codigo donde voy metiendo code al array?

Comment: necesito saber donde pasas el dato code , por que ese dato es el numero dentro del array

Comment: por ejemplo, vos pones algo asi supongo int code = 0; o donde obtienes el valor que quieres pasarle para que borre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final di con el codigo:

```
public void deleteEvent(View view) {

        eventos = new ArrayList<>();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child( uiD );
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                User listas =dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                eventos=listas.getevents();

                for( int i=0; i<listas.getevents().size();i++){
                    if(eventos.get( i ).equals( code )){
                        eventos.remove( i );
                        users.getevents().remove( i );

                        databaseReference.setValue( users );
                    }
                    if (eventos.contains( code )){
                        eventos.remove( code );
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );

    }
```